# Font-face does not work on Android Ice Cream Sandwich browser

Tags: android, css, font-face

I'm using font-face on my website `(Teuton23ProRegular)` and the font is not coming through on `Android ICS` (tried native browser and Firefox), and looking good on all other desktop and mobiles I've tried `(Android Gingerbread, iPhones, Win Mobile)`. Mobile firebug revealed this error:

```
Error: downloadable font: not usable by platform (font-family: "Teuton23ProRegular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2)
Source File: http://[sitename]/../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.woff
Line: 0
```

Source Code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Teuton23ProRegular';
src: url('../../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.eot');
src: url('../../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
     url('../../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('../../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('../../css/fonts/teuton23pro-webfont.svg#Teuton23ProRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Another interesting thing is that the font I got from http://fonts.com/ works fine `("Trade Gothic W02 Bold 2")`.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If Trade Gothic W02 Bold 2 is working but not Teuton23ProRegular then by logical deduction the problem probably lies in the content of the font files or the font-face declaration.

I am not familiar with Android IceCream Sandwich Browser's font rendering and the format it utilizes (looks like it uses .woff given the error notice) but it seems like the Teuton23ProRegular font-face file is not working because:

- a) it is lacking one of the eot, eot fix, woff, truetype or svg formats
  (whichever icecream uses but place particular emphasis on .woff)
- b)
  it does have the proper font format variant but its faulty or
  corrupted
- c) you have some mispelling or rogue comma somewhere in
  your code?
- d) you accidentally did not upload the correct format file
  and thus its not being loaded

Please double check all of the above by comparing how you declared Teuton23 versus the Trade Gothic equivalent.